# General verb for animal making sound

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds, onomatopoeia, animals

English language has [different verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds) for different species of animals making sound, many are onomatopoeias.  But is there a general verb that can be applied to an unnamed animal?  e.g., can I say "I heard an animal cry" (replace *cry* with the appropriate verb) when I can't tell what animal is making this sound?

Comment: I heard an animal noise.

Comment: @Jim yes, but sometimes one might want a verb to emphasize the action.

Comment: Well then choose a verb that describes the sound...

Comment: @Jim well, there's a long list of possible verbs to remember

Comment: I heard an animal make a sound/noise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Cry' is a generic term - the most generic term - that you can generally use for any animal or bird, but because the sound is indeed onomatopoeic, there are are general words for different categories of types of sound - for example:

- bellow - is low and deep
- roar - is a loud deep sound, like a lion
- call - is a higher pitched maybe repetitive conversational sound, eg birds

And so on, a useful list is published here:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/sounds-made-by-animals